# Potential Virus Undetected by AVG?

Tags: virus, avg-antivirus

recently some files have been showing up (only 2 as far as im aware) in our families old laptop. most of the others aren't concerned about them, nor do they care, the laptop is years old and close to breaking down. however, i am worried some sort of virus or program has been put on our computer and would like to ask the kind people of the internet for your opinions.

I have added links to images of said files onto this post.

the files are not where the properties say they are (and are not hidden) and are also not able to be shredded by AVG, AVG also claims they are not a threat. I cannot read the file names.

i you require more information for analysis then i can provide more as long as it doesnt invade the security of the laptop.

Images: https://imgur.com/gallery/GTfcN

Comment: Are you using AVG free?

Answer (score 0):

First, there's no such thing as 100% detection. The claims of 100% detection are a bit of marketing trickery and legal hackery meant to give buyers warm fuzzies about the product in their hands. And a sudden urge to part with their money.

In your case, however, these look like files with kanji characters in the file names. ::shrug:: You have an anime character for your avatar. How do *you* think the files got there? There's likely nothing at all harmful or dangerous about them but if you want to be sure you should be able to use AVGs tools to submit the files to a forensic computer specialist working for AVG who can inspect the "code" of the file to be sure it is nothing harmful or dangerous.

I say "should" because AVG is cra... what? I can't spread my opinion on SuperUser? Well, what's the fun in that? Fine... yeah... you *should* be able to submit the files for further testing.

Comment: I also don't rate AVG. If very often doesn't appear in the top 5 or 10 anti virus apps, where as often (not always) Kaspersky, Bit Defender and Comodo. So I'd suggest removing it, instant and trying with another to see... That should give user a little more confidence